# Does every elliptic cohomology theory represent a complex-orientable $E_\infty$-ring spectra and vice-versa?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, spectral-sequences, sheaf-cohomology

The last paragraph in [Two-Vector Bundles and Forms of Elliptic Cohomology](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306027.pdf) remarks that neither the spectrum $K(ku)$ nor tmf is complex orientable. In the case of $K(ku)$: "...the unit map for $K(ku)$ cannot factor through the complex bordism spectrum $MU$, since $\pi_1(MU)=0$."

This confuses me, is it not the case that every elliptic cohomology theory represents a complex-orientable [$E_\infty$-ring spectra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137764/what-are-e-infty-rings) and vice-versa?

On page 21 of [Lurie's Survey](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/survey.pdf), he mentions:

> If we view $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ as the classifying space for complex
>   line bundles, then the group algebra $\Sigma[\mathbb{CP}^\infty]$ can
>   be viewed as a universal cohomology theory in which it is possible to
>   add line bundles. The above result can be viewed as saying that if we
>   take this universal cohomology theory and invert the Bott element
>   $\beta$ then we obtain a theory which classifies vector bundles. A very
>   puzzling feature of the result is the apparent absence of any direct
>   connection of the theory of vector bundles with the problem of
>   orienting the multiplicative group.

Does this mean we have no functorial, multiplicative choice of Thom classes for complex vector bundles in tmf and $K(ku)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither $K(ku)$ nor tmf are complex orientable, so neither $K(ku)$ nor tmf are elliptic cohomology theories in the strict sense. $K(ku)$ "is" an elliptic cohomology theory in the looser sense that it "detects $v_2$-periodic phenomena" (although I can't elaborate too much on what this means), and tmf "is" an elliptic cohomology theory in the looser sense that it is built out of all elliptic cohomology theories somehow.

Comment: Why is Bott periodicity a $v_1$ periodic phenomena, (besides that K-theory is associated to the multiplicative formal group law which is of height 1)?

I don't understand why the height of the formal group law associated to a complex orientable cohomology theory is relevant to the periodicity of the cohomology theory.

Comment: My understanding is that tmf is "built" out of elliptic cohomology theories in the following way:

Take the taylor series expansion of an elliptic curve $E$ about the origin, you'll get a formal group law over a coefficient ring $C_E$.

Varying the curve $E$ in the the Landweber-Stong construction, $MU^*(X)\otimes_{MU^*(pt)} C_E$, will give us a family of elliptic cohomology theories (assuming $C_E$ is Landweber-exact). 

Taking the limit of this family (over the category of elliptic curves), we get tmf.

Comment: @fractalcows: I believe that description of tmf is incorrect, roughly speaking because the structure of the category of elliptic curves does not know what it means for a family of elliptic curves to vary over a scheme. One needs something like the derived moduli stack of elliptic curves; this is Lurie's approach. I don't know anything about $v_n$-periodicity, so I'm not the one to ask about that; in particular I don't know what it has to do with Bott periodicity.

Comment: @Qioachu I just read over [Akhil Matthew's post](http://goo.gl/HsAo7R). If I understand correctly, the description I gave of the Landweber-Stong construction was correct, but can be instead phrased as:

An elliptic curve is a one-dimensional algebraic group (more generally, a group scheme) $C$ over a ring $R$, which we can write as $C \to \text{Spec}(R)$, where $\text{Spec}(R)$ is a ring spectrum (a commutative monoid in the stable homotopy category). (What is $R$ here? Is it what I called $C_E$ in my previous post, or is it like  $y^2 = 4x^3 + ax + b;  a, b \in R$)

Comment: Allow me to correct some of the errors in my past 2 comments: $C_E$ arises from the ring that parameterizes the coefficients in the family $C \to \text{Spec}(C_E)$ (e.g. $ y^2=4x^3+ax+b$; $a,b \in C_E$); $\text{Spec}(C_E)$ is emphatically not the a ring spectrum in the sense of a commutative monoid in the stable homotopy category, but instead the spectrum of a ring, in the sense of a functor from $\text{Ring} \to \text{Scheme}$.